# Pointing to specific inheritance

Tags: c++

When I was writing my class, I found a new problem about inheritance. My C++ GCC compiler (and other compilers too, of course) doesn't know what to do: cast `*this` to `uint32_t` and then from `uint32_t` to `my_class`, or just use `my_class operator<<` overload. **I want compiler to use the second variant always with `my_class`**.

Frankly speaking, I don't know how to solve the problem. Do I need some special keyword?

Simple example with the same problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

class my_class
{

public:

    std::bitset<32> _data;

    my_class(const std::bitset<32>& x) : _data(x) {}

    my_class(const uint32_t x) : _data(x) {}

    operator uint32_t() const {
        return _data.to_ulong();
    }

    my_class operator<< (uint32_t pos) const {
        return my_class(_data << pos);
    }

    my_class foo() const {
        // Some code...
        my_class tmp = (*this << 1); // This line produces warnings
        // ...
        return tmp;
    }

};

int main()
{
    auto entity = my_class(42);
    entity.foo();
}
```

Warnings of compiler:

```
source_file.cpp: In member function ‘my_class my_class::foo() const’:
source_file.cpp:25:34: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
         my_class tmp = (*this << 1); // This line produces warnings
                                  ^
source_file.cpp:19:14: note: candidate 1: my_class my_class::operator<<(uint32_t) const
     my_class operator<< (uint32_t pos) const {
              ^
source_file.cpp:25:34: note: candidate 2: operator<<(uint32_t {aka unsigned int}, int) <built-in>
         my_class tmp = (*this << 1); // This line produces warnings
```

Comment: `1` is not an unsigned int.

Comment: There is confusion as to what you intend. It may convert `*this` to `uint32_t` (with `operator uint32_t() const`), shift that value then convert it to `my_class` (with `my_class(const uint32_t x)`) or it my call `my_class operator<< (uint32_t pos) const` on `*this`.

Comment: Your question is not related to inheritance.

Comment: It's diamond problem, isn't it? [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)

Comment: @AlexanderStanovoy No, you don't even have inheritance so multiple inheritance is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why implicit conversions should be avoided. When you do

```
*this << 1
```

You could call `operator uint32_t() const` and then shift, or call `my_class operator<< (uint32_t pos) const` and convert `1` to a `uint32_t`. Either way, there is a conversion, so both become an equal match and thus an ambiguity.

There are a couple of ways to fix it.  First, just mark the conversion operator as `explicit`. Using

```
explicit operator uint32_t() const {
    return _data.to_ulong();
}
```

allows the code to compile as it forces it to use you overloaded `operator <<`. You could also switch to using `_data` directly like

```
my_class tmp = (_data << 1);
```

and this will also compile.